# how to get last "shiftID" row entry in sql table mysqli

Tags: php

Hi i have a php form and part of this is to get the last "shiftID" row entry in my table and put this into a variable so i can later add 1 to said variable. However the result of the following code returns the information linked below. How do i get the last "shiftID" number by itself into a variable.

```
    <?php
session_start();
include 'dbh.php';

$start = $_GET['starttime'];
$finish = $_GET['finishtime'];
$dat = $_GET['date'];
$id = $_GET['userid'];

$shiftidd = $conn->query("SELECT shiftID FROM shift_user ORDER BY shiftID DESC LIMIT 1");
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($shiftidd);
echo print_r($row[0]);
//$result = $conn->query("INSERT INTO shift (shiftStart, shiftFinish, shiftDate) 
//VALUES ('$start', '$finish', '$dat')");

//$sql = $conn->query("INSERT INTO shift_user (shiftID, userID) VALUES ('$shiftidd', '$id')");

//header("Location: shifts.php");
?>
```

Web page result:
"connected 41"

I'm looking for the number "4" but I'm guessing the "1" is the affected row along with the result? but how do i get rid of the "1"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably need to use `mysqli_fetch_field` instead of `mysqli_fetch_row`

Answer (score -1):

1 is a result of *print_r()* which is superfluous here. Use *either* echo or print_r, but not both

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like. After you insert query executed use the following function

```
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName,LastName,Age)
VALUES ('Glenn','Quagmire',33)");
$id = mysql_insert_id();//will return you the last id inserted into table//
```

But if you want to find the last id of some table then you have to use the follwoing code:

```
    $shiftidd = $conn->query("SELECT MAX(shiftID) FROM shift_user LIMIT 1");
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($shiftidd);
echo print_r($row[0])///////it will be the last id of the table////////
```

if you want to find next id please try  this

```
$shiftidd = $conn->query("SELECT MAX(shiftID)+1 FROM shift_user LIMIT 1");
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($shiftidd);
echo print_r($row[0])///////it will be the next id of the table///////////
```